# Windows Impersonation with Redemption

Tags: impersonation, outlook-redemption

I want to access pst stored on the other machine where i don't have any rights.I am trying LogOnPstStore() for the same under the identity of that machine/user
using Windows Impersonation. but getting the error MAPI_E_NOT_ENOUGH_RESOURCES.

I have also created the seperate exe for the same and called it with CreateProcessWithLogonW() but at that time i am getting following error :

Could not find the newly added PST service
   at Redemption.IRDOSession.LogonPstStore(String Path, Object Format, Object DisplayName, Object Password, Object Encryption)

Can you help me ?Is It Possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, MAPI and impersonation do not play well with each other. Secondly, and more importantly, Microsoft does not support PST files on network drives.